# how can I solve error "object 'X1' not found" in network_plot?

Tags: r

Greetings to all I'm a rookie with R and I'm trying shinyApp. my problem is that

When running application launches the following Error:

> ** object 'X1' not found **

Could someone tell me what is wrong?
Thank you

```
library(shiny)
library(corrr)



ui <- fluidPage(

  box(plotOutput("plot1")),


)

server <- function(input, output) {
slidervalues  <- reactive({
  data.frame(
  color = c("mixto", "negro", "atigrado"),
  peso = c(2.1, 5.0, 3.2),
  le_gusta_cuerda = c(1, 0, 1),
  le_gusta_jugar = c(2, 6, 1)
  )
})

output$plot1 <- renderPlot(                    

  network_plot(correlate(slidervalues()[,-1]), min_cor=0.4)

  )

}
```

## Run the application

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
slidervalues <- data.frame(
  color = c("mixto", "negro", "atigrado"),
  peso = c(2.1, 5.0, 3.2),
  le_gusta_cuerda = c(1, 0, 1),
  le_gusta_jugar = c(2, 6, 1)
)


network_plot(correlate(slidervalues[,-1]), min_cor=0.4)

Correlation method: 'pearson'
Missing treated using: 'pairwise.complete.obs'

Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'X1' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In stats::cmdscale(.) : only 1 of the first 2 eigenvalues are > 0
```

The problem is not shiny related, but I think because of a too small dataset.

```
slidervalues <- data.frame(
  color = c("mixto", "negro", "atigrado", "test"),
  peso = c(2.1, 5.0, 3.2, 10),
  le_gusta_cuerda = c(1, 0, 1, 10),
  le_gusta_jugar = c(2, 6, 1, 5)
)


network_plot(correlate(slidervalues[,-1]), min_cor=0.4)
```

This code works and will also work in Shiny. Just a little tip: Since you do not filter the dataframe or anything, there is no need to use a reactive expression. Only do that when results can change.

Comment: with more values ​​works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help, Markus, I still have a lot to learn. I will consider your tips

Comment: you are welcome :-). If you are happy with my solution, please update and/or accept my solution :-)